# Sympy RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded when solving equation with logarithms

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm trying to solve a simple equation with logarithms in sympy, however I get a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` when I try to execute the code. Here is what I am doing:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

pH = sp.Symbol("pH")
pCO2 = sp.Symbol("pCO2")
HCO3 = sp.Symbol("HCO3")

myhco3 = 10.0**(7.0 - 6.1 + np.log10(0.03 * 44.0))


hh = sp.Eq(pH, 6.1 + sp.log(HCO3, 10) - sp.log(0.03 * pCO2, 10))
eqs = [hh,
       sp.Eq(pH, 7.0),
       sp.Eq(pCO2, 44.0)]

result = sp.solve(eqs, dict=True)
print result
```

The error occurs on the line where I try to `sp.solve` for the equations. This seems like a fairly simple equation to solve. Is there some sympy assumption that needs to be set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a symbolic solution, based on algebraic manipulations (which is what SymPy is for), you should avoid floats as much as possible. For example, 6.1 is represented as 3433994715870003/562949953421312 in double precision, and when a coefficient like that meets logarithms, algebraic manipulations can easily produce a polynomial equation of degree like 1933167165348049724692481703936 which won't lead anywhere good. If instead of

```
hh = sp.Eq(pH, 6.1 + sp.log(HCO3, 10) - sp.log(0.03 * pCO2, 10))
eqs = [hh, sp.Eq(pH, 7.0), sp.Eq(pCO2, 44.0)]
```

you write

```
hh = sp.Eq(pH, sp.Rational('6.1') + sp.log(HCO3, 10) - sp.log(sp.Rational('0.03') * pCO2, 10))
eqs = [hh, sp.Eq(pH, 7), sp.Eq(pCO2, 44)]
```

the output will appear at once:

```
[{pCO2: 44, pH: 7, HCO3: 33*10**(9/10)/25}]
```

Take-away points:

1. If your coefficients are floating-point numbers and you expect a floating-point output, you want a numeric solver (see [SciPy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.1/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#sets-of-equations)) not a symbolic one.
2. For a symbolic solution, make sure the numbers involved in the equation have clean algebraic structure: `sqrt(sp.Rational('6.1'))`, for example.

Comment: Does Numpy have a subpackage that can be flexibly used to numerically solve equations?

Comment: I misremembered; it's in scipy.optimize. Added a link to the answer.

Comment: Great, I'll take a look. I'm very familiar with Numpy, but I find more goodies in Scipy all the time. Thanks for the thorough answer, marking as correct.

Comment: You can also use `sympy.nsolve` to solve SymPy equations numerically.